# Android Studio Layout Editor blank

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I downloaded the latest Android Studio 2 days back. The layout editor is blank even after I drop widgets (like `Button`, `TextView` etc.) from the palette.

The component tree in the left-column shows that the widgets have been added to the editor, so I know drag-drop is working, but nothing shows up on the display screen of the layout editor.

What is causing this and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Try changing the `theme` of LayoutEditor.

Comment: Try Invalidate and restart android studio.

Comment: select Theme of your project than check.

Answer (score 5):

Have You Added dependencies for design view? If not here it is

go to app level build.gradle, add the dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:xx.x.x'
```

appcompat version will depend on your compileSdkVersion.

finally, sync the gradle file

Comment: Is correct dependencies of API 28  are causing blank view for layout not showing widgets. So use Support library 27.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Change the android xml themes like AppTheme/AppTheme.NoActionBar....or try to restart Android Studio.

Check the Latest Android Studio Version AS 3.1.1